# Show videos to user which is selected by admin

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

I have one admin and many user. Admin have rights to upload,delete and select the users.
User only watch those which admin select 
so the problem is how admin select a users for a specific video 
For example if admin select user1,user2 and user3 for a xyz video so thai xyz vedio only appear to user1,user2 and user3 
I hope you understand my problem please help me thanks

Comment: What are you asking here exactly? What is the programming problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a question.

Comment: Sounds like you need a hierarchy of permissions to the videos assigned by the Admin.

Comment: What exactly is the question? How to enforce the admin role? How to model a M:N relation between user and video? How to filter videos in a select statement by users based on their assigned videos? We need a bit more clarification and specificity.

Comment: Admin selects the users from admin panel and the video only apper to those selected user in user panel

Comment: Ok so we understand the scenario. What exactly is the problem then? You want help designing the database, or what? You didn't actually explain what you want help with

Comment: Thanks all I got a solution thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think, I understood your problem.

You must have two tables one for user and one for videos.

what you need to do is to create a pivot table between these two this table will contain three columns mainly you can add other fields too but the three columns you need are id (the unique value), user_id (primary key from the user table) and last is the video_id (primary key from videos table).

Now on the playlist page get all the videos which the pivot table have in it.